# Can't add cookie using setCookieString in FireFox 22

Tags: firefox, cookies

When trying to add cookie using setCookieString in firefox 22 the cookie isn't saved if the domain of the cookie doesn't already exist.

The code I used:
cookieSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"].getService(Components.interfa‌​ces.nsICookieService); 
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.in‌​terfaces.nsIIOService); 
cookieUri = ios.newURI(domain, null, null); 
cookieSvc.setCookieString(cookieUri, null, cookieStr, null);

Is anyone know if it's a bug? and what is the way to solve it?

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: var cookieSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieService);
var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
cookieUri = ios.newURI(domain, null, null);
cookieSvc.setCookieString(cookieUri, null, cookieStr, null);

Comment: in the OP would be great too :)